# Shortening boolean with if statement for document version comparison

Tags: c#

Can this be shortened to one line?

```
 bool areVersionsEqual = documentComparer.Equals(version, imported);

if (areVersionsEqual == false)
  {
    changedDocument.Add(imported); 
   }
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Sure. Use the [Not operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f2kd6eb2.aspx).

```
if (!documentComparer.Equals(version, imported))
{
    changedDocument.Add(imported); 
}
```

---

To explain a little, it's bad practice to do things like this.

```
bool boolean = true;
if (boolean == false)
{
//...
```

because it's completely equivalent to saying

```
if (true == false)
```

and can be simplified down to

```
if (false)
```

Comment: This is not technically "one line" though.

Comment: can you use a regular expression for example?

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg no. It's not. You're right, but we're not here to *obfuscate* code.

Comment: @user3437721 there's no where near enough context to say whether or not that could be done, but I wouldn't recommend a regex over this nice simple code that you have. If the regex should be anywhere, it should be in your `DocumentComparer`. Programming is all about abstractions, and `DocumemtComparer` seems to be a nice one.

Comment: @user3437721 Why are you asking about regular expressions now suddenly? Something tells me that you haven't provided anywhere near enough context here. What is it that you *really* want to do?

Comment: no this is fine, good answer - at the end of the day I just wanted to improve what was there.  I 'thought' a one line snippet would be better, but obviously this is not the case here.  Thanks for your help

Comment: @user3437721 You could write one line without an IF statement (at least in JavaScript): `documentComparer.Equals(version, imported) && changedDocument.Add(imported);`. It depends on the mechanism of [short-circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation). While that being a topic you should know about, it doesn't justify producing a kind of bizarre one-liner.

Comment: @user3437721 since you have two operations your trying to accomplish (determining if the versions are equal & adding the imported document if they are) with the second operation being conditional, a one line solution is impossible or ugly. You could achieve a one-liner in this file by adding a method to changedDocument's class like: `changedDocument.AddIfNotEqual(version, imported, documentComparer);`

Answer (score 9):

I believe it could be a one line, but I don't think you should.

One liner's are kind of "cool" to write, but they are a pain to debug, and a pain to read.

I think you should keep your variable, it is great for readability.

What I would change though is the indentation of your `if`. Bring those brackets to be on the same line as the `if`.

And, as @RubberDuck pointed, you should use the `!` operator instead of `== false`.

```
bool areVersionsEqual = documentComparer.Equals(version, imported);

if (!areVersionsEqual)
{
    changedDocument.Add(imported); 
}
```

I think this looks better then if you do it on **one** line.

Comment: Pedantic comment: in a language which uses true/false (cf yes/no), `versionsAreEqual` would probably be a better name

Comment: You're right! I didn't really checked the variable name as it was okay.

Answer (score 1):

You can make this one line by moving the boolean statement into the conditional and removing the unnecessary brackets (You don't need brackets with a single line conditional).  This code is perfectly legal syntax:

```
if (!documentComparer.Equals(version, imported)) changedDocument.Add(imported);
```

I consider it good style to remove brackets when they're not necessary.  It saves vertical space.  Note that the length of this line is 79 characters.  When you use a shell, the default line width is 80, any more than that and your lines start wrapping which makes it difficult to read.  Nominally I'm okay with anything 80 characters or less.  Some people prefer 76 characters because when you're showing line numbers in an editor they take up the first 4 characters, leaving you with only 76 characters until the line wraps.  If you want to make everyone happy, I would write it like this:

```
if (!documentComparer.Equals(version, imported)) 
    changedDocument.Add(imported);
```

You could also include your brackets in a single line conditional like this:

```
if (!documentComparer.Equals(version, imported)) { changedDocument.Add(imported); }
```

Of course this brings you up to 83 characters so I would curse you to programming hell!

Do **not** use a ternary operator.  It's not necessary and it only serves to confuse the code, as there is no else statement.

Also do **not** use a short circuited logical operator to turn this into a one liner.  It's confusing and it wouldn't even be syntactically correct in C#.

Comment: Okay. Better. I truly believe you should *always* use brackets. [Big bad bugs happen when you omit them.](http://embeddedgurus.com/barr-code/2014/03/apples-gotofail-ssl-security-bug-was-easily-preventable/)

Comment: Bracket standards are a never ending argument among developers. If you're working in a professional environment you should always adhere to the standards set forth by your development team. That said, the question was about turning this into a one liner and not about bracketing philosophy.

Comment: any and all facets of the code are up for review. We often mention things that don't directly relate to OP's question here. If you don't believe that it's best practice to just always use the brackets, I highly recommend that you read the link I posted.

Answer (score -1):

Technically, yes you can make this a single expression:

```
documentComparer.Equals(version, imported) || (changedDocument.Add(imported), true);
```

Don't do that, though. :) Instead, I would take RubberDuck's solution.

Comment: This works in C#?? I tried real quick but I can't get it to work. Is there doc about this... thing? :p

Comment: That's invalid syntax. The result of the second part after `||` would have to return a boolean value, and it won't in this case.

Comment: In Javascript, there is a synthax identical to this one that specifies : If left part `==` false, execute operation on the right. This is why I asked if it existed in C#

Comment: Oh, drat. My mistake. I thought C# inherited the comma operator from C/C++, but now I see that it doesn't. (I didn't realize I was on MSDN's C++ pages when I looked it up.)

Answer (score -5):

You could try a ternary operator

```
documentComparer.Equals(version, imported) == false ?  changedDocument.Add(imported) : break;
```

crappy? Yes

Comment: How is this supposed to compile? 1. You can't use the ternary operator as a statement in C#. 2. How is that `break` supposed to work? What are you breaking out of?